# Python class print object always returns an empty list

Tags: python, class, oop

I have the following code:

```
class Mylist(list):

    def __init__(self,lst=[]):
        self.lst=list(lst)

    def append(self,item):
        self.lst.append(item)
m=Mylist([1,2])
m.append(3)
m
```

Intuitively, this code should print [1,2,3] or maybe [3]? but definitely not []. I am wondering why is this happening? Although when I use m.lst instead of just m, then it prints [1,2,3].

Comment: .... why are you overriding the `list` class to add an attribute that *is a list* which you then redirect `.append`'s to???

Comment: @donkopotamus Just don't use it *unless you understand it's semantics*. Here, it should work just fine.

Comment: Anyway, your code prints `[1, 2, 3]` so I cannot reproduce your issue...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  It does not print [1,2,3]

Comment: `m` however, will definitely print `[]`.... why did you think it would do something different?

Comment: The problem is not giving [] as the parameter to __init__. even if you remove that m will still be []

Comment: Yes it does, it prints `Hehe [1, 2]` and then `hoho [1, 2, 3]` on another line

Comment: The problem is you do not understand the difference between inheritance and composition. Why are you inheriting from `list`???

Comment: Guys do not try to judge me why I did that. This is a piece of code and I am trying to understand why the output is like this

Comment: I'm not "judging" you, I'm trying to understand your questions and expectations. You keep talking about "printing", but your code prints exactly what you'd expect. Note, a line wiht `m` *doesn't print anything* unless you are in a REPL, in which case it prints `repr(m)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `MyList` inherits from `list`, it already contains internal storage for items that `append` (and `extend`) would normally add to. When you `print(m)` it is this *internal* storage that is shown.

In your case you have then overridden `append` to redirect items to be added to a separate attribute (`lst`), meaning that internal storage remains empty.

Note that you have not overridden `extend`.  Thus:

```
# this will add to the *internal* storage, not `.lst`
>>> m.extend(["my", "gosh"])`
>>> print(m)
['my', 'gosh']
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mylist` doesn't in any way utilize the fact that it's subclassing `list`. Your code would work if `list` actually had a `lst` attribute that itself was a list, but this is not the case.

You need to use the exposed interface of the `list` object that you inherited from if you want your overridden methods to do things that are picked up by the underlying `list` object:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        print('I was passed:', iterable)

        super().__init__(iterable)

    def append(self, element):
        print('I am appending the element:', element)

        super().append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *use* a list, you don't need to inherit from `list`, and shouldn't:

```
class Mylist: # no (list) here!
    def __init__(self,lst=[]):
        self.lst=list(lst)
    def append(self,item):
        self.lst.append(item)
m=Mylist([1,2])
m.append(3)
```

This works. Of course printing out `m` will just get you something like `<__main__.MyList at 0x12345678>`, because you haven't told it how you want to be printed. You need to add another method like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__, self.lst)
```

And now you'll print out `MyList([1, 2, 3])`.

---

If you want to *look* like a `list`, you still don't inherit from `list` for that. In most cases, in Python, "looking like a list" is just a matter of duck-typing: you implement all the right methods, and everything just works.

However, you might want to consider inheriting from [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). Then, you just implement about 7 or 8 methods, and you get the whole rest of the `list`'s behavior for free. And you're also providing a way that code that, for whatever reason, needs to explicitly check whether you "act like a list" can do so.

---

So, when *should* you inherit from `list`? When you want to use the `list`'s internal storage and implementation as your own.

Here's a silly example. To the extent that it has any reason to exist at all, it's reasonable that it should be a `list` subclass:

```
class FreezableList(list):
    def frozen_copy(self):
        return tuple(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__, self.lst)
```